# Create Jquery fadein and fadeout on hover text

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

How to a create a fadein and fadeout effect on this http://jsfiddle.net/b3FgY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li", "#list-gallery").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("h2").fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find("h2").fadeOut();        
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use fadeIn and FadeOut instead of show and hide.

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/b3FgY/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li", "#list-gallery").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("h2").fadeToggle();
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/b3FgY/4/)**